# Why the javascript polyfill execution giving error?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, module, polyfills

I have written a custom polyfill for reduce and trying to execute in **repl**. But I'm getting an error saying **arr.getReduce is not a function!**
Here's my code:

```js
const arr = [2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 0, 9, 2, 3, 4];

Array.prototype.getReduce = function(callback, initialVal) {
  let accumulator = initialVal === undefined ? undefined : initialVal;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (accumulator !== undefined)
      accumulator = callback.call(accumulator, this[i], i, this);
    else
      accumulator = this[i];
  }
  return accumulator;
}

const sum = arr.getReduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + ' , ' + b;
}, 1) // Initial Value is 1
console.log(sum);
```

I'm trying to execute it but getting the following error:

```
TypeError: arr.getReduce is not a function
at /home/runner/NewPractice/index.js:92:15
at Script.runInContext (vm.js:131:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (/run_dir/interp.js:156:20)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
```

I want to know why this issue coming up like this and the solution regarding this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your snippet works fine here.

Comment: @Barmar But while trying to execute the same in repl, I'm getting the error!

Comment: You also probably want to use: `callback.call(this, accumulator, this[i], i, this);`

Comment: @NickParsons I applied **this** at the start as you mentioned but still getting the error in **repl**

Comment: @Subhojit can you recreate the issue in repl and share/add a link to it in your question?

Comment: Nick's comment was not related to the error, it's just a logic error in the function.

Comment: Actually it probably should be `callback.call(null, ...)`. The callback is not a method, it shouldn't receive `this` as the context.

Comment: I suspect the problem is with how you're using the repl. You're probably starting a new JS execution session for each statement.

Comment: @Subhojit yeah, my issue was mainly pointing out a logic error (which you will get once your code runs), you actually probably want to use something a little different to the `.call()` method I showed as `.reduce()` doesn't seem to use the array as the default context, but rather the global object instead

Comment: Okay, got it @NickParsons